# How to convert a date-time vector into UTC?

Tags: python, numpy, utc

I have date-time data in a text file (six columns (YYYY, MM, DD, HH, MM, SS)). I required to convert the data into UTC time. But, there is an error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index". May someone suggests to me how to fix this. My script is as below:

```
names = ["year","month","day","hour","minute","second"]
df1 = pd.read_csv('tim.txt',sep='\t',names=names)
t_series1=pd.to_datetime(df1[names])
t=np.array(t_series1)
time = UTCDateTime(t)
print(time)


#Data formate is like 

#2015   2   13  19  30  12
#2015   2   16  23  38  28
#2015   3   30  0   33  31
#2015   4   24  13  59  15
#2015   4   25  7   4   26
#2015   4   26  8   2   11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

utc_dt = datetime.strptime('2011-01-21 02:37:21', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

From there, you can use the `strftime()` method to format the UTC datetime as needed:

```
utc_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't list the original timezone, let's say it's `Europe/Rome`, you can convert it to `UTC` with:

```
pd.to_datetime(df1).dt.tz_localize("Europe/Rome").dt.tz_convert("UTC")
```